# Why am I getting DUP ACK from the HOST and re transmissions from the SERVER

Tags: wireshark

When I see the trace in the wire shark, what I see is the client sending DUP ACK to the server and the server keeps on Retransmitting the data. What does this situation signify? how can I correct this?

Comment: Please describe where you are doing the packet capture. Ideally it should be at both ends. Then describe what packets you see at each location you captured.

Comment: the problem is very simple i just want to understand when do we send DUP ACK ??

Comment: Because the server retransmitted the original packet, of course, and thus must not have received the first ACK. I thought you wanted to know why the server retransmitted, for which you need to provide more information.